# How do I engage in hand to hand combat?

Tags: resident-evil-5

I'm not sure I understand how to get into hand to hand combat in RE5.  It seems that I occasionally get a hint to press <kbd>F</kbd> and make hooks, but other than that and the machete, I don't see a way to just punch or kick an enemy.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shinrai said, it's all context sensitive, but be aware that if you do manage to punch someone, your partner can perform a second hit for more damage, and then you can hit them one last time for a lot more damage. Bouncing them back and forth can be quite fun. Zombie Pong!

Comment: Ooh, I've never played co-op.  That sounds fun.

Comment: any idea how do you create the situation where hooks, straights are available?

Comment: You have to stagger the enemies, so shoot them in the leg and they'll grab their leg in pain. Or shoot them in the head and they'll be off balance for a couple of seconds. Then get close and you should have the melee option. Not sure if you can then run up to them and do parts 2 and 3 of the melee (don't think so) but your AI partner often responds in kind!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing something here; you can't melee at will (with the exception of the knife).  All that other stuff is indeed context sensitive.

Comment: any idea how do you create the situation where hooks, straights are available?

Comment: AFAIK, you just have to be in range and the enemy has to be staggered from other attacks.